# Passing Ruby variable to xtractr query

Tags: ruby, variables

I have my data in an array(src_ip). I want these data to be passed as a parameter to xtractr queries. Could somebody please help me with this?
This is my code:

```
src_ip=Array.new

src_ip=open("/home/sakshi/Desktop/test/src_ip.txt", &:read).scan(/#<host:(.+?)>/).flatten

i=0

n=src_ip.length

while i != n

p xtractr.packets('pkt.src:src_ip[i]').sum('pkt.src','pkt.length')

i+=1

end
```

Here, I want to pass the array(src_ip) to the xtractr query(xtractr.packets...)in the while loop. I am unable to do this.

Comment: The whole array or the entries of the array one at a time? It seems like you want one at a time from the code snippet however your question says "I want to pass the array"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each entry passed in individually you do this:

```
src_ip.each do |i|
   p xtractr.packets("pkt.src:#{i}").sum('pkt.src','pkt.length')
end
```

If you want them all at once:

```
p xtractr.packets("pkt.src:#{src_ip}").sum('pkt.src','pkt.length')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!This is what I exactly wanted...I wanted to pass one at a time and your solution perfectly worked for me.